# WebSocket connection to 'wss://api.chatengine.io/person_v4/?session_token=st-7b6efb7e-b283-4337-a5f2-a1ab9b471ee0' failed:

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-chat-engine

i'm working on a chat application using Reactjs and Chat Engine my app is not workin due to this error message :

```
"WebSocket connection to 'wss://api.chatengine.io/person_v4/?session_token=st-7b6efb7e-b283-4337-a5f2-a1ab9b471ee0' failed: ".
```

[image]

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

After trying to connect directly to `wss://api.chatengine.io/person_v4/?session_token=st-7b6efb7e-b283-4337-a5f2-a1ab9b471ee0` using https://www.piesocket.com/websocket-tester **it failed once** with the exact error you provided, **then connected successfully** three times on two consecutive attempts.

Do try again.

I wanted to suggest contacting support with chatengine.io being a private service, however from the last page of the [Terms & Conditions](https://www.linkedin.com/in/adam-la-morre-87104b142/?originalSubdomain=ca), the e-mail address listed there points to a suspended Squarespace account so might not work.

So the next suggestion is to find a better (actively maintained) service.